# cakephp structure of source code view

Tags: cakephp, meta

I wonder why this:

```
<?php
    echo $this->Html->meta('icon');
    echo $this->Html->meta('shortcut icon');
    echo $this->Html->css(array('style', 'backtop'));
    echo $this->Html->script(array('jquery-1.7.min', 'superfish', 'jquery.responsivemenu', 'jquery.flexslider', 'jquery.easing.1.3', 'jquery.ui.totop'));
    echo $this->Html->meta('keywords', 'enter any meta keyword here');
    echo $this->Html->meta('description', 'enter any meta keyword here');
?>
```

ends up in

```
<link href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" rel="icon" /><link href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" rel="shortcut icon" /><meta/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/backtop.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/superfish.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.responsivemenu.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.ui.totop.js"></script>
```

Why are some lines nicely underneath and others in one line?
Where does the closing  comes from? You'll find it behind the shortcut tag.

I checked other *cake* sites from `cakephp.org` and they do not seem to have the same issue as I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
    echo $this->Html->meta('icon');
    //echo $this->Html->meta('shortcut icon');
    echo $this->Html->css(array('style', 'backtop'));
    echo $this->Html->script(array('jquery-1.7.min', 'superfish', 'jquery.responsivemenu', 'jquery.flexslider', 'jquery.easing.1.3', 'jquery.ui.totop'));
    echo $this->Html->meta('keywords', 'enter any meta keyword here');
    echo $this->Html->meta('description', 'enter any meta keyword here');
?>
```

do not you `echo $this->Html->meta('shortcut icon');` because in cakephp not handling the type "shortcut icon" as meta. that's why it is giving only .

Following will give you both the meta tags.

```
echo $this->Html->meta('icon');

<link href="/cake/caketest/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" rel="icon" /><link href="/cake/caketest/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" rel="shortcut icon" />
```

Comment: OK, great, I didn't know that! Thanks! Do you also have an idea why some metas are not line by line? I mean, its not a problem at all, it's just that I wonder why this happens?